# Customize Woocommerce emails notification content based on order status

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am trying to customize email notifications based on a custom **"shipped"** order status…

This is the normal template display:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php if( ! $order->has_status('shipped') ) { ?> 
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order has been delivered to your provided shipping address and we marked its status to <b>completed</b>. Let us know if you have any questions.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p> 
<?php } ?>
```

But now I have a repetition:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? How to avoid that repitition?

The code structure of my `emails/customer-completed-order.php` template *(extract)*:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ ?>
<?php if( ! $order->has_status('shipped') ) { ?> 
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order has been delivered to your provided shipping address and we marked its status to <b>completed</b>. Let us know if you have any questions.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p> 
<?php } ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order has been marked complete on our side.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your actual template structure by the following *(you have a duplicated line)*:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ ?>
<?php if( ! $order->has_status('shipped') ) { ?> 
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order has been delivered to your provided shipping address and we marked its status to <b>completed</b>. Let us know if you have any questions.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p> 
<?php } ?>
<?php
```

Now it should works.

Comment: This works great I used two statement. `<?php if( ! $order->has_status('shipped') ) { //my html code here }?> ` and `<?php if( $order->has_status('shipped') ) { //my html code here }?> `

I don't know if it is the right way to do this but it works. :p